# CD DVD BD - Does it spin left or right?

Tags: dvd, blu-ray, cd, rotate, disc

So, how do those discs spin? Clockwise or counterclockwise? I cannot find any information on the topic.

Comment: https://youtu.be/UTx9l6XFBlU?t=72

Comment: So clockwise then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO/IEC 10149:1995 "Data interchange on read-only 120 mm optical data disks (CD-ROM)" says:

> #### 11.2  Direction of rotation
>
> The Physical Tracks shall spiral outward when the disk rotates counter-clockwise as seen by the optical stylus.

Which sounds like it's clockwise if you're looking from the top and counter-clockwise if you're looking the way the laser would be looking at it.